# break or continue a for or while/do..while/for..in/for..of loop from a callback function inside of its' body?

Tags: javascript

I'm in a bad situation where it's not too simple to test in order to get the answer.

is the following code correct in JavaScript?

```js
while(condition){
  const response = await queryingSomeServer().catch(error => break) // notice here
}
```

what about other loops, (not the array ones, like forEach or filter, I know these don't have *break* or *continue* keywords), but what about the `for()` loop? what about the `for(.. of ..)` loop, and what about the `for(.. in ..)`.
is that possible?

- if not:
  is the following going to work?

```js
while(condition){
  try{
    const response = await queryingSomeServer()
  }
  catch(error){
    break
  }
}
```

- do you think there is a cleaner code?

Comment: The second snippet looks reasonable - but repeated polling in the first place is inelegant and weird. Sometimes you don't have any other option, but sometimes you do.

Comment: @CertainPerformance , so that means the first and second snippets are correctly written, and syntatic valid, and does the samething, right? thanks Performance.

Comment: You cannot `return break`. And `break` will always apply on the immediate scope block [`for`, `while`, etc]. So, you'll need to "play" with variables to achieve what you need. Similar to the 2nd snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first snippet's syntax is not valid. You can only `break` when an immediately outer *block* is a loop; you can't break from inside a callback.

Your second snippet looks pretty reasonable, it'll work:

```js
(async() => {
  let condition = true;
  while (condition) {
    try {
      throw new Error();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('breaking');
      break
    }
  }
  console.log('out of loop');
})();
```

But polling in the first place is inelegant and weird. If at all possible, figure out if there's a better way to structure things, so that the *server* can communicate to this client when the process can end, instead of the client having to continually poll the server.